# Connecting to Azure Container Services from Windows 8.1 Docker

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-service

I've been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wjxpng6jYs&t=1333s) tutorial to set up an Azure container service. I can successfully connect to the master load balancer via putty. However, I'm having trouble connecting to the Azure container via docker.

`~ docker -H 192.168.33.400:2375 ps -a
error during connect: Get https://192.168.33.400:2375/v1.30/containers/json?all=1: dial tcp 192.168.33.400:2375: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

I've also tried
`~ docker -H 127.0.0.1:2375 ps -a`
This causes the docker terminal to hang forever.

`192.168.33.400` is my docker machine ip.

My guess is I haven't setup the tunneling correctly and this has something to do with how docker runs on Windows 8.1 (via VM).

I've created an environment variable called `DOCKER_HOST` with a value of `2375`. I've also tried changing the value to `192.168.33.400:2375`.

I've tried the following tunnels in putty,
1. `L2375 192.168.33.400:2375`
2. `L2375 127.0.0.1:2375`
3. `L22375 192.168.33.400:2375`
4. `L22375 127.0.0.1:2375` (as shown in the video)

Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

Here are some screenshots of the commands I ran:

[image: putty_tunnel_config]

[image: putty_docker_run_command]

[image: docker_terminal_run_command]

Comment: Can you run `docker info` on your windows 8.1?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't show any Nodes from ACS. Is there another piece of data I should be looking for?

Comment: Does it show information of your local docker?

Comment: Yes, here's some of it.
```
Server Version: 17.06.0-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 29
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
Kernel Version: 4.4.74-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 17.06.0-ce (TCL 7.2); HEAD : 0672754 - 
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
```

Comment: Ok, please delete other tunnel information, just keep `L2375 localhost:2375`

Answer (score 0):

We can follow this steps to setup tunnel:

1.Add Azure container service FQDN to Putty:
[image]

2.Add private key(PPK) to Putty:
[image]

3.Add tunnel information to Putty:

[image]

Then we can use `cmd` to test it:

[image]

Comment: `Strategy: spread`  
`Filters: health, port, dependency, affinity, constraint`  
`Nodes: 0`  
`Swarm:`  
` NodeID:`  
` Is Manager: false`  
` Node Address:`  
`Kernel Version: 3.19.0-65-generic`

Almost everything is the same as your last screenshot, but I still read 0 nodes. I tried `docker -H 127.0.0.1:2375 pull centos` but I get a `Warning: Empty registry endpoint from daemon. Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/` error.

Comment: Can you login to your Azure container service master VM and run this command?

Comment: `docker info` on my ACS master VM putty connection shows the name as `swarm-master-xxxxx-0`, `Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/`, 2 containers, 2 running, 2 images, `Server Version: 17.10.0-ce`, `Swarm: inactive`. Not sure if I'm supposed to look for something specific. It doesn't mention Nodes. `docker -H 127.0.0.1:2375 ps -a` shows no running containers. The two running containers on the ACS master VM are a `containers_swarm_1` and `containers_consul_1` (checked using the putty connection)

Comment: @syntaxerror can you find nodes in your Azure resource group?

Comment: Inside my resource group I see swarm agent load balancer, master load balancer, couple of storage accounts, swarm master VMs, and network interfaces. Everything here was auto generated.

Comment: Please run this command "docker -H 10.0.0.5:2375 info" in your master. We can find the private Ip address of the agent in Azure portal Vnet.

Comment: That command returns `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://10.0.0.5:2375. Is the docker daemon running?`

Comment: Have you find your private IP address of your Agent? Is the private IP address is `10.0.0.5`? By the way, after you tunnel completed, putty will SSH to your master, does that SSH tunnel setup and you can run command in that VM?

Comment: Running that command in the putty terminal connected to the master returns `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://10.0.0.5:2375. Is the docker daemon running?`, and running it in a local docker terminal returns `error during connect: Get https://10.0.0.5:2375/v1.30/info: dial tcp 10.0.0.5:2375: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party
 did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.`
I guess the private IP address is not `10.0.0.5`?

Comment: @syntaxerror we can find the private IP address via Azure portal,

Comment: The IP address of my `swarm-agent-vmss (instance 0)` is `10.0.0.4`. I get the same results as before when I run `docker -H 10.0.0.4:2375 info`.

Comment: I opened a putty connection to the master and ran the command. It returned `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://10.0.0.4:2375. Is the docker daemon running?`

Comment: to troubleshoot this issue more efficiently, could you please capture the screen and post it to your question?

Comment: @syntaxerror It seems there are something wrong with your ACS, have you try to restart your master and agent?

Comment: I restarted the VMs and tried again with the same results. However, I managed to get my hands on a Linux machine and running `docker -H 127.0.0.1:22375 ps -a` returned `Error response from daemon: No elected primary cluster manager`. Is this the problem? If so, how can I fix it?